# Upload file via Form and Spring

Tags: html, spring-security

in my web page(HTML+JS) i have a option for upload files to the server (JSP+Spring) right now i have this form for upload :

```html
<form :form action="uploadfile.htm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" target="_blank" modelAttribute="listFile">
  <table id="tableupload">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="files[0]" type="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="up file" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </f:form>
```

when i submit the server responds and open new window . can I catch this response without opening the new window?

Thankyou.